Добавить ограничение по вводу символов
Добавить функцию, в которой можно было бы ввести только цифры , длина вводимых символов от 3 до 4 .
Ввод цифр сделано (вроде правильно), а по количеству вводимы символов не разобралась


export function kod(element) {
  return element.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
}



если ввели 1-2 символа должно выйти сообщение с ошибкой,
если 3-4 - сообщение об ошибке должно пропасть
а на ввод 5 и более - запрещен(не вводятся символы)

Как вы введете сразу 3 символа не вводя 2 предыдущих? копировать-вставить? А если ввели 1-2 или 5 и более, какое поведение ожидается?

@user615545 а вы уверены, что это тот пользовательский опыт, который вам нужен? Представьте, пользователь начал что-то вводить (1 символ), а вы ему сразу ошибку выводите. Лучше выводить сообщение об ошибке при потере фокуса полем ввода. Если очень хочется вы можете дополнительно, в процессе ввода, проверять, чтобы вводились только цифры и из было не больше 4.

а как можно добавить проверку на ввод только цифр и ограничить до 4 символов?

element.match(/^\d{3,4}$/) !== null.

Добавила такой код, вроде бы работает:


export function kod(element) {
  let val = false;
  if (element.length < 3 || element.length > 3 || !Number(element)) {
    val = true;
  }
  return val;
}



